How to publish and subscribe from and to device in iot hub?
Currently I'm trying to send a temperature data to my azure iot hub using publish (python) and at the same time I'm trying to read or receive the temperature data using subscribe method in another python code both code runs through command prompt.
so far the result is either one is to connected to the device. Can't I do as per the below image.

code publish
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
 
# Define the connection string for your device
CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=iothub-jein02-np-eas-ua-eztr01.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=NodeMCU;SharedAccessKey=pOkHxKaDejoJUSgUU3ZdmKqG/KV3XOcbgILSX8ZDiMk="

# Create an instance of the device client using the connection string
device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
 
# Connect the device client
try:

    device_client.connect()

    time.sleep(5) 

    temperature = random.randint(0, 100)
    # Create message payload 
    message_payload = { "temperature": temperature } 

    # Create a message
    message = Message(str(message_payload))
 
    # Send the message to IoT Hub
    device_client.send_message(message)
    
    print("Message sent to Azure IoT Hub successfully.")
except Exception as ex:
    print ( "Unexpected error {0}" .format(ex) )

 
# Disconnect the device client
device_client.disconnect()

code subscribe
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
 
# Define the connection string for your device
CONNECTION_STRING = "<your-device-connection-string>"
 
# Define the callback function to handle received messages
def message_received_callback(message):
    print("Message received from Azure IoT Hub:")
    print("    Data: {}".format(message.data))
    print("    Properties: {}".format(message.custom_properties))
 
# Create an instance of the device client using the connection string
device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
 
# Set the callback function for handling received messages
device_client.on_message_received = message_received_callback
 
# Connect the device client
device_client.connect()
 
# Keep the application running
input("Press Enter to exit...\n")
 
# Disconnect the device client
device_client.disconnect()


please  share the code you tried

for connection string I used iothubowner primary string
and also tried device connection primary string also and SAS token

what was the error you are getting?

do want to send  random temperature

I'm not getting error I'm running both the code at a time one is connected and another one is not connecting
if I run publish first it will get connected and send data then I run subscribe code the publish code gets disconnected from hub and subscribe is waiting for the message.

can you add time.sleep(5)  and  temperature = random.randint(0, 100)
        # Create message payload
        message_payload = {
            "temperature": temperature
        }

        # Create a message
        message = Message(str(message_payload))

        # Send the message to IoT Hub
        device_client.send_message(message)


now subscribers should add continuously listening for messages with time.sleep(5)  and run the about code.

which connection string I should use for both

Check with Device connection

It says could not connect to iothub

In expection  right ?

yes, raise exceptions.ConnectionFailedError("Could not connect to IoTHub") from e
azure.iot.device.exceptions.ConnectionFailedError: Could not connect to IoTHub

Can you add ex to track ex in your code

updated the code the error now I'm getting is "Unexpected error Could not connect to IoTHub"

please share error now

Unexpected error Could not connect to IoTHub

Reference this SO if helped let me now

IoT Hub is not a full MQTT broker and is not intended for device to device communication using a publish/subscribe model.
IoT Hub lets you use device-to-cloud or cloud-to-device messaging. The device client object you're using can be used to send messages to the cloud to be received and processed in the cloud. The message you send using the device client isn't available to receive using a device client.
If you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/tutorial-send-telemetry-iot-hub?toc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&pivots=programming-language-python, you'll see that the device connects using a device connection string, and messages are read from the hub after a utility connects using a hub connection string.
If you're looking for an Azure hosted MQTT broker that supports pub/sub, take a look at Azure Event Grid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-overview
